# can't able to implement log4j for JBOSS EAP 7 using java?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

i have an application, i have applied log4j, but i can't able to create log file inside jboss application.
when i put absolute path of system in `log4j.appender.file.File= D:/log/application.log` it was working fine but when i put  `log4j.appender.file.File= ${jboss.server.home.dir}/log/application.log` it is not working.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File= ${jboss.server.home.dir}/log/application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `$JBOSS_HOME` instead of `${jboss.server.home.dir}`.. so it becomes

```
log4j.appender.file.File= ${JBOSS_HOME }/log/application.log
```

Comment: could you please tell me, should i need to set JBOSS_HOME as variable name?